# How do I position correctly a weather radar image (taken from Met Office DataPoint API) in MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, ios, mapping, mkmapview

here http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/datapoint/product/precipitation-forecast-map-layer it says that the image tile i am trying to overlay in MKMapView is:

> provided without a map, the boundary box for this image is 48° to 61°
>   north and 12° west to 5° east.

Given that how do I plot the image using MKOverlay correctly.

Also once plotted as the user scrolls and zooms do I have to re-draw/re-render the image.

any help much appreciated.

Comment: I sorted the anchoring issue, I was misreading it - obviously 12 degrees west = -12.0.

Although having now plotted them in mkmapview the images look poor when zoom level is high. Sadly it seems the Met Office thinks the images they currently provide are "high res".